# NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element during web scrape

Tags: c#, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to scrape this website:
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g293718-Algiers_Algiers_Province.html

I used this code:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g293718-Algiers_Algiers_Province.html");
        
var collection = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='cauvp Gi o']"));

foreach (var item in collection)
{
    string name = item.FindElement(By.XPath(".//a[@class='bHGqj Cj b']")).Text;
    string location = "Algiers";
    string type = item.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[@class='bhDlF bPJHV eQXRG']/span/span")).Text;
    IWebElement img= item.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[@class='bdLpT w carousel fjXXd ddFHE']/div/ul/li/div"));
    
    string image = img.GetCssValue("background-image").Replace("url(\"",string.Empty).Replace("\")",string.Empty);
    string link = item.FindElement(By.XPath(".//a[@class='bHGqj Cj b']")).GetAttribute("href");
}
```

But I got this error message:

> NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//a[@class='bHGqj Cj b']"} (Session info: headless chrome=101.0.4951.67)

Comment: The expression in your code is `.//a[@class='bHGqj Cj b']`, but in your error message it is `./a[@class='bHGqj Cj b']`. This makes a serious difference. Maybe this is the cause of your problem?

Comment: @zx485  I was trying both ./ and .// . both ./ and .// give the same error, i corrected my post

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Change

```
 string name = item.FindElement(By.XPath(".//a[@class='bHGqj Cj b']")).Text;
```

To

```
 string name = item.FindElement(By.XPath("//[@class='bHGqj Cj b']")).Text;
```

Comment: Still getting same error

Comment: I am looking at the XPath value and this is what I get on chrome `//*[@id="component_2"]/div/div[2]/span/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span/a` . Can you verify using firepath add-on on firefox?

Comment: Also there are many elements with this class so you will need to call `string name` inside a `foreach()` loop .

Comment: yes i called string name inside a foreach, i just didn't complete the whole code

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is carving text out of the element using the class.

```cs
foreach(var item in collection(".//a[@class='bHGqj Cj b']//text()[normalize-space() and not(ancestor::span)]")) {
string name = item.InnerText.Trim();
}
```